nextjs "Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined"
My code is like below
'use client';
 
import {
  UserGroupIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  DocumentDuplicateIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import clsx from 'clsx';
 
// ...
 
export default function NavLinks() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
 
  return (
    <>
      {links.map((link) => {
        const LinkIcon = link.icon;
        return (
          <Link
            key={link.name}
            href={link.href}
            className={clsx(
              'flex h-[48px] grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3',
              {
                'bg-sky-100 text-blue-600': pathname === link.href,
              },
            )}
          >
            <LinkIcon className="w-6" />
            <p className="hidden md:block">{link.name}</p>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

why this error raised ?
and how to solve it ?
(An error occurs when you try to 'use client;')
this code from nextjs official tutorail code :
https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/navigating-between-pages
Thank you.

In Next.JS the behavior may depend on the file path/name as well. And is this NextJS version 13 or 14?

thank you for answer, my nextjs version is 14.

I encountered the same issue and managed to resolve it by changing the NavLinks component to a named export/import
export function NavLinks() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
  //...
  )
}

In sidenav.tsx,
import { NavLinks } from "@/app/ui/dashboard/nav-links";


This fixed it for me. Thank you!

Thank you! It is these kind of difficult to diagnose issues in introductory exercises that are the most frustrating. This solved it for me.

What even is this error due to? I see no mention in docs that client components can't be default exports...? In fact, this docs page example uses a default export.

This error occurred during the step where I used 'use client'. I resolved it by stopping and restarting the development server with npm run dev, which made it work.

Same issue, but @LAMEfreak's answer didn't work for me. So, I clicked the link suggested by Next.js error page and I did what it said, running next command in terminal:
pnpm add next@canary

restarted the app and it worked for me.
